# jQuery add up multiple items

Tags: php, jquery

What would be the best way to calculate the price of my cart? Would it be better to grab the price from the database or put it in code. So far I put it in my code but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
    <script>
var b = 0, v = 0
$("input[name='compcase'], input[name='caselight']").change(function() {
    b=$("input[name='compcase']:checked");
    v=$("input[name='caselight']:checked");
    b=b.length==0?0:parseInt(b.attr('data-price'));
    v=v.length==0?0:parseInt(v.attr('data-price'));
    $('.test').html(b+v);
});
</script>
<body>
<p class="test"></p><br><br>

<Form name ="pc" Method ="Post" ACTION ="radiobutton.php">
<img src="http://www.pureoverclock.com/wp-content/uploads/images/review/cases/nzxt_phantom410/nzxt_phantom410_4.jpg" width="150" height="180"></img><br>
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='compcase' value= '1' data-price='25' />NZXT Phantom Enthusiast USB3.0 Full Tower Case - White <br />
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='compcase' value= '2' data-price='25' />Corsair Obsidian 750D Large Tower Case Black <br />
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='compcase' value= 'Cooler Master CM Storm Trooper' data-price='25' />Cooler Master CM Storm Trooper Black Full Tower Gaming Case <br /><br />

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='caselight' value= 'Red' data-price='60' />Red<br />
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='caselight' value= 'Green' data-price='60' />Green <br /><br />
```

**EDIT:**

Ok so. Basically, depending on which radio button I click, so far I only have a compcase table set up for price, the subtotal will change. Here is my table: http://gyazo.com/9fe4daf2d76b2174fb0f6f6fdb04aaf4 and here is my radio buttons: http://gyazo.com/fbcfd7814bb3a03ad768ae33bb0d37eb

Comment: works fine **[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XvGoJgxX3utozFmfuM2i?p=preview)**   did you forget to wrap in a ready handler?

Comment: now I have a question: would it be better to somehow get the price from a table in the database instead of doing this as prices may fluctuate daily and there could be many pages like this so it seems like a waist of time going through the code when I can just update it in the database?

Comment: depends if this is hard coded or `data-price` is being created dynamically

Comment: thing is, I'm pretty new to database so all this is very in depth. Im surprised I've gotten so far. data-price currently is hard coded. It doesn't connect to the database whatsoever.

Comment: makes no sense to hard code it if you expect it to change then

Comment: how would I go about making it connect with the database? the radio buttons insert the data to a table so how would i go about making it work together?

Comment: I just set up a little something. I might work on this code:

Comment: <?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `compcase` WHERE 1") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Description:</th> <td>".$row['name'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Price:</th> <td>".$row['case_price'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
 ?> 

seems to be working ok right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for information,

If you don't rely in this price for the end of the cart process it's ok. Otherwise you would have serious problems with products being sold cheapier.

A sugestion would be an request to update the value, this way you could apply discount with multiple itens in cart and many other things...

Sorry, I can't comment with my reputation..

@UPDATE

You could get all checked radios:

```
var checkedItems = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
```

And send it to a PHP (or anything else) to process and return what you need:

```
$.post('url/to/a/processor', checkedItems.serialize(), function(data) {
     //update the cart price from data
});
```

In the backend:

```
<?php 
// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error()); 
$checkedCompcase = isset($_POST['compcase']) && !empty($_POST['compcase']) ? $_POST['compcase'] : null;
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM compcase WHERE id IN ($checkedCompcase)") or die(mysql_error());

// treat data and sum up your cart, apply discount, whatever you need

// return data
header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
// define what you need in the frontend and return what is expected
echo json_encode(array('cart' => array('value' => $sum, 'items' => array()));
```

**Just don't forget to treat all data sent to database queries**

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: is this easy to connect to a database or no?

Comment: If the answer is what you needed, please, accept it ;)

Comment: can i add this to the side of my radio buttons somehow?

Comment: what you mean with "to the side"? You mean to call it when you check the radio?

Comment: So basically, Subtotal: will already be printed and when i click one of the options, the subtotal will add up

Comment: Well, that can be done with a <span class="subtotal" />.. 
$('.subtotal').html(subtotal); within the ajax return.. I personally like the idea of not relaying with front-end calcs for this kind of thing, but as already mentioned, you can sum up all the items and just show it.. Did I understood you correctly?

Comment: here is exactly what i want. https://www.cyberpowersystem.co.uk/system/INFINITY_XTREME_SE

Comment: basically, when you click one of the radio buttons, it adds it up on the left hand side.

Comment: That can be done from the ajax response.. and injected with .html(), as I said, within the response you can do all those things getting content from backend.

Comment: can I have an example of the ajax response?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon after your variable declaration:

```
var b = 0, v = 0; //<--you missed this
```

With that fixed, it works fine, as per this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3mjkw7w9/

Comment: semi colon won't make the difference when there is a line break. Not best practice but not a code breaker either